# Csurf Forbidden Error: invalid csrfToken code: 'EBADCSRFTOKEN' in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, csrf

In my blog project, csrf works fine on some post routes like login, register, logout, update account information,... but in the admin routes, when I tried to create/update a post or a category - it failed and threw the forbidden error. I tried many solutions from other questions but nothing worked for me.

```
require('dotenv').config();

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const csrf = require('csurf');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
const uri = process.env.URI;
const app = express();
const csrfProtection = csrf();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secrets',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: uri,
      autoRemove: 'native',
      ttl: 7200, //2 hours
      collectionName: 'sessions',
    }),
  })
);
app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.name = undefined;                //
  res.locals.level = 0;                       //
  if (req.session.user) {                     //
    res.locals.name = req.session.user.name;  //those line for render nav bar in views
    res.locals.level = req.session.user.level;//
  }                                           //
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

// routes
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const pageRoutes = require('./routes/page');
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');

app.use(pageRoutes);            //
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);   //everything works fine
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes); // errors

// error pages
app.use(errorController.get404);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).render('errors/500', {
    pageTitle: '500',
    error: error,
  });
});

mongoose
  .connect(uri)
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

And I have put this input in every post form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken%>" />
```

The error when I logged it out:

```
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at csrf (D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\csurf\index.js:112:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)      
    at next (D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\express-session\index.js:506:7
    at D:\Tai lieu hoc tap\Code\Personal Projects\Blog\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:221:17
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'EBADCSRFTOKEN'
}
```

Thanks for every answer! Because I can learn something from everyone here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here came from enctype in the form tag. While updating in auth routes only about texts so I use default enctype (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), but updating a post or category may update a new image so I use multipart enctype with multer.

Just need to add a query in form action with the name = _csrf, value = csrfToken. No more error.

Before:

```
<form action="/admin/update-post" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

After:

```
<form action="/admin/update-post?_csrf=<%= csrfToken%>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```